# Navigation View Selected Menu Item Checked In Other Activity?

Tags: android, navigationview

i am Using Material Design Navigation View..i created Menu item And linked activity(Activity2.java) with an item(Starred)...and in that activity i extend my Main activity in which there is navigation view so that i can slide the navigation view from that activity too.. but when i slide the navigation view from the second activity the item is not checked and if i press the back button and go to the Main activity the previously checked menu item is shown...how to update the check item in other activity.please help

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining Variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.inbox:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.starred:

                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class));
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.sent_mail:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.drafts:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drafts Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.allmail:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Mail Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.trash:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trash Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.spam:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Spam Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();






    }
}
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends MainActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
        // inflate the custom activity layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_2, null,false);
        // add the custom layout of this activity to frame layout.
        frameLayout.addView(activityView);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer.xml(menu_drawer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/inbox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox_black"
            android:title="@string/inbox_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/starred"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black"
            android:title="@string/starred_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/sent_mail"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_black"
            android:title="@string/sent_mail_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drafts"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black"
            android:title="@string/draft_string" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/allmail"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black"
            android:title="@string/all_mail_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/trash"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
            android:title="@string/trash_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/spam"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_error_black"
            android:title="@string/spam_string" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you provide the xml code of the navigation drawer?

Comment: Done!! do u know how to do it

Answer (score 5):

1. Add a `protected int` variable for storing id of checked menu item
2. From NavigationView's clickListener add checked menu item id to intent's extras; start yours second Activity with this intent
3. In second activity get menu item id from extras and set it to class variable from (see 1)
4. add onPrepareOptionsMenu in yours super-Activity

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        //recreate navigationView's menu, uncheck all items and set new checked item
       navigationView.getMenu().clear();
       navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer);
       //setChecked(false) to all yours menu items in NavigationView
       navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.SOME_ID_0).setChecked(false);
       navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.SOME_ID_1).setChecked(false);
       navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.SOME_ID_2).setChecked(false);
       ...etc
       navigationView.setCheckedItem(checkedDrawerItemId);
    }
   ```
5. in yours NavigationView's clickListener do not forget to set clicked item's id to Activities class variable and call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();`

Comment: actually mohax i am new to android and i am not familiar with above things..could be please elaborate more about that extras and all

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Activity 2 :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.starred).setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: *error* Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: You must search for menuItems in navigationView instead of menu. See my answer.