# How to setChecked the itemMenu in a new Activity with drawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, appcompatactivity

In my code I have a BaseActivity that implements a MenuDrawer, and I have 3 activities that extends from BaseActivity.
The 3 activities are started from the menu drawer, each item from the menu leads to an activity.
My problem becomes when I start a new activity, and I want to keep de setChecked item on menudrawer.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701615), but there are somethings that this guy doesn't explain.

I need an example, beacuse I been looking for this on internet and found nothing.
If is needed, i can upload some code to show what im doing.

Thanks!

Comment: In the link you have provided...he is using navigation view with drawer layout...so please search tutorial for navigation view and you will find answer.If you need a navigation drawer. In short you need         menuItem.setChecked(true);

Comment: Im using NavigationView, i do it but my problem is that each time I start an activity, the view is being created, to solve this I pass the item position as an extra to the intent, and then start the proper activity with that intent. and then, i have implemented the method mentioned in the solution, but still not working, I dont know exactlywhere to put this method: supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();. This method is supposed to call onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu Menu); but doesnt work..